# Create a login class in Robotframework and use it in a test case to login

Tags: robotframework

I am new to Robotframework. 
I am trying to see if there is a reusable concept in Robotframework. I want to create a login class and use it in my other test case to login. How can I do this in Robotframework? 
Can we create functions in Robotframework and use them in test cases? Any simple example would be help.

Answer (score 2):

The way you do this in robot framework is to create a reusable [keyword](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#creating-user-keywords). 
For example, your keyword might look like this:

```
*** Keywords ***
| Log in to our application with
| | [Arguments] | ${username} | ${password}
| | Input text | id=username | ${username}
| | Input password | id=password | ${password}
| | Click button | id=submit_button
```

You could then use it in a test case like this:

```
*** Settings ***
| Library        | Selenium2Library
| Suite Setup    | Open browser | ${APP_ROOT} | ${BROWSER}
| Suite Teardown | Close all browsers

*** Test Cases ***
| Example test case
| | Log in to our application with | test_user | S3cr3tPa55w0rd
| | Page should contain | Welcome back, test_user
```

You don't have to put this all in one file. You can put the keywords in a [resource file](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#resource-files), and import it into as many test suites as you want.

Comment: Thank You, Got it. Just looking to see if i can use classes but this one will help me.

Comment: @KumarGangi: robot framework doesn't have the concept of classes. The framework isn't a programming language. Keywords are the fundamental reusable objects.

Comment: Thank you. Do we need to make them as resource file if i need them for reuse in other test suites?

Comment: @KumarGangi: yes. For them to be reusable they need to be in a resource file or library.